# Install Spark using sparklyr and spark_install error

Tags: r, windows, apache-spark, sparklyr, azure-dsvm

I am attempting to install spark using sparklyr and

```
spark_install
```

and I get the following error.

```
    C:\dsvm\tools\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin\tar.exe: Cannot use compressed or remote archives
C:\dsvm\tools\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin\tar.exe: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
running command 'tar.exe -zxf "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\rstudio\spark\Cache/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz" -C "C:/Users/LeviVM/AppData/Local/rstudio/spark/Cache"' had status 2�tar.exe -zxf "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\rstudio\spark\Cache/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz" -C "C:/Users/LeviVM/AppData/Local/rstudio/spark/Cache"� returned error code 2Installation complete.
cannot open file 'C:\Users\MyPc\AppData\Local\rstudio\spark\Cache/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/log4j.properties': No such file or directoryFailed to set logging settingscannot open file 'C:\Users\MyPc\AppData\Local\rstudio\spark\Cache/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/hive-site.xml': No such file or directoryFailed to apply custom hive-site.xml configuration
```

Then I downloaded spark from the web and used

```
spark_install_tar
```

This gives me the same error:

```
C:\dsvm\tools\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin\tar.exe: Cannot use compressed or remote archives
C:\dsvm\tools\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin\tar.exe: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a vague memory that windows users have specific requirements to get sparklyr to install. You should do some searching on windows installs of spark. I'm not sure you are yet ready to ask any R questions.

Comment: Thanks. I have spent a huge amount of time searching about this but to no avail.

Comment: Then you should cite the material that you were following in efforts to install spark. You don't seem to have `log4j`. When I searched I found this immediately on SO with a Google search: How to set Spark log4j path in standalone mode on windows?

Comment: Would you kindly post the links?

Comment: We now have pre-installed Spark standalone in the Microsoft Azure Data Science Virtual Machines (DSVM) - both Windows 2016 edition and the Ubuntu Linux edition. If you spin up a new instance of the DSVM on Azure you shoudl be able to leverage the preinstalled Spark standalone instance for your development.

Answer (score 1):

When I upgraded sparklyr using

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")
```

The issue went away

Answer (score 0):

spark_install_tar(tarfile = "path/to/spark_hadoop.tar")

if you still getting error, then untar the tar and set spark_home environment variable points to spark_hadoop untar path.

Then try executing the following in the R console.
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")